# How can I add a custom right aligned image on Navbar with setRightBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem, appearance

I'm in xcode 4.3 targeting iOS 5.1 and I'm trying to have a logo appear in the right hand side of ALL navbars in my app.

First I used the following code in EVERY view controller to make it work

```
UIButton* fakeButton = (UIButton *) [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"driftlogo_header.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem *fakeButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:fakeButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = fakeButtonItem;
```

Problem with this is that I have to do it in every view controller, but some of my views aren't classed. I want to reduce code and wanted to use iOS 5 appearance property to set this globally from the app delegate.  I've tried

```
UIButton* fakeButton = (UIButton *) [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"driftlogo_header.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem *fakeButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:fakeButton];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setRightBarButtonItem:fakeButtonItem animated:YES];
```

Doesn't work, error unrecognized selector sent to instance.  Same error for

```
UIButton* fakeButton = (UIButton *) [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"driftlogo_header.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem *fakeButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:fakeButton];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setRightBarButtonItem:fakeButtonItem];
```

What is the correct way to set this from app delegate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you managed to solve it?